# octree vs graph data structure

Tags: python, data-structures

I need to implement in python a data structure that each node in the data structure represents a rectangle on a plane.
the operation that I need from the data structure is:

1) split a node, that split a rectangle into 4 rectangles with the same 
   size(in the end I suppose to get something like from A to B in this  [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5RZB.png))

2) get all neighbor rectangles(for some computation)

Up to now, I thought about two options both of them not optimal, the first one is to use some kind of octree/quadtree which make the splitting very easy but I'm not sure about finding all the neighbor rectangles. the second is a Graph which enables me to find the neighbors very easy but makes it difficult to split a node.

I didn't succeed to think about an elegant solution for doing both things, and I will appreciate suggestions, even better if they are implemented in a python library.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question?